# Fitting data using a differential equation

Tags: differential-equations, fitting

I have data generated from two functions given below. How can I go about
finding a fit of the form:

```
y'[x] == -(a + b/(c + d  y[x] + e F[x] ))
```

where a,b,c,d,e are to be determined?

```
F[x_] := If[x < 37.5, 2.80 + 0.0036 x, 117.86 - 6.314 x + 0.0865 x^2]

s = NDSolve[{y'[x] == -(0.0595 + 3716/(11780 + y[x])) y[x], 
   y[0] == 650000}, y, {x, 0, 60}]


data = Table[{x, Evaluate[y[x] /. s], F[x]}, {x, 0, 60, 1}]
```

Comment: @Nasser ...error corrected

Comment: What are the triplets in `data` ? Is it `{x, y[x], y'[x]}` ?

Comment: @b.gatessucks It is {x,y[x],F[x]}

Comment: @thils, I believe you have to approximate y'[x] based on the data using finite difference coefficients. Have you considered this?

Comment: @caya, No I have not considered this...it looks like a possibility for x>37.5 (pls see F[x_]) due to the discontinuity....so perhaps  I should narrow down to x>37.5?

Comment: @thils, I noticed that the solution from `NDSolve` was differentiable already; hence my answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a task for [`FindFit`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FindFit.html). First, get the solution from `NDSolve` as a function; let me call it `solY`.

```
F[x_] := If[x < 37.5, 2.80 + 0.0036 x, 117.86 - 6.314 x + 0.0865 x^2];

solution = 
  NDSolve[{y'[x] == -(0.0595 + 3716/(11780 + y[x])) y[x], 
    y[0] == 650000}, y, {x, 0, 60}];

solY = y /. First[First[solution]];
```

Now, generate the data in a format for `FindFit`. In this case, as you want `y'[x] == -(a + b/(c + d  y[x] + e F[x] ))`, my suggestion is to have two independent values, `y[x]` and `F[x]` giving the dependent value `y'[x]`. `x` is not required. **Note that you can use the derivative `solY'`!**

This data is generated by the following

```
data = Table[{solY[x], F[x], solY'[x]}, {x, 0, 60, 1}];
```

Now, feed that into `FindFit`, like

```
FindFit[data, -(a + b/(c + d  v1 + e v2)), {a, b, c, d, e}, {v1, v2}]
```

and you get

`{a -> 11425.8, b -> -2.63417*10^9, c -> 1.01206*10^7, d -> -98.9974, 
 e -> -213696.}`

The derivative `solY'` comes from an approximation (numerical solution to `NDSolve`), so I would double check results by other means. Also, your parameters are non-linear and "In the nonlinear case, it finds in general only a locally optimal fit." (see documentation)

Hope it helps.

**Update**

As mentioned by OP, `FindFit` does not find a good answer. `F` is itself problematic and certainly one would like to explore the data. Here some ideas on how to do this, but consider that the parameter space is 5D - so visualization is already hard.

You can use the solution to define a new function. This is a way to do it. Say you capture the solution into `resp`, like `resp = FindFit[...];`. Then you can do

```
g[v1_, v2_] := Evaluate[-(a + b/(c + d v1 + e v2)) /. resp];
```

Using `?q` actually gives `g` with values from the solution rules.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can define then a new *data* to compare.

```
data2 = Map[({#1, #2, g[#1, #2]} &) @@ # &, data];
Show[
  ListPlot3D[data2, 
    ColorFunction -> (Directive[Red, Opacity[0.7]] &)],
  ListPlot3D[data, 
    ColorFunction -> (Directive[Blue, Opacity[0.7]] &)],
PlotRange -> All]
```

which gives you

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Again, hope it helps.

Comment: Appear to work fine, except that I got  "Failed to converge to the requested accuracy or precision within 100 iterations"...with slightly different set of a,b,c,d,e. Possibly I need to change the model slightly?

Comment: @thils, I am not sure about your problem space. I added few ideas you can use. Good luck!